# How to configure feeds module JSONpath mapping, when all information is on the same (root) level?

Tags: feeds, 8

I would like to import content with [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) with [JSONPath extensible parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) and create nodes of them.

When I have a hierachical JSON with a parent, the mapping is working like a charme (e.g. context: $.article.* / source: $..title).

My problem occures, when the JSON contains a single content (that should be imported to a single node) and all relevant elements are on the first/root level. This guy had a similar problem, although in my case I even do only have one content per JSON doc ([Link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/feeds-jsonpath-parser-i-need-help-using-available-variables)), but with the suggested solutions I do not get it work.

{

"identifier": "test0004",

"title": "This is a title",

"application": "Drupal",

}

I don't have any clue, what context and what source I have to define, to make it work. As context I desperately tried-I believe-everything, amongst others:

- .
- .*
- $
- $.*
- $[]

And as source $.title, $title, title etc.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried a few things, can't get it to work either. However, I'm working on adding support for the library "flow/jsonpath" in the D8 version of Feeds extensible parsers. With that library, I can confirm that just a dot `.` works as context in this case. Tested on https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/#jsonpath.

Do note that your JSON example has an error: the comma after the last item should be removed.

Comment: Thank you for you efforts in testing and reproducing my problem. I installed flow/jsonpath. So it seems to be a module problem?

Comment: A module problem - yes and no. Feeds extensible parsers cannot handle this use case with the peekmo/jsonpath library, but with flow/jsonpath it could. But the D8 version of Feeds extensible parsers does not yet support flow/jsonpath. I'm close to finalize that, however.

Comment: Thank you for the information and thank you for your efforts to improve the module.